# Using functions to interpret external txt file

Tags: python, function

Using an established function I need to call it to interpret an external txt file and output the amino acid codes into the console

translate function interprets input DNA.

txtTranslate is supposed to interpret txt file DNA.

> External file contains:
>   ACATTTGCTTCTGACACAACTGTGTTCACTAGCAACCTCAAACAGACACCATGGTGCATCTGACTCCTGA
>   GGAGAAGTCTGCCGTTACTGCCCTGTGGGGCAAGGTGAACGTGGATGAAGTTGGTGGTGAGGCCCTGGGC
>   AGGCTGCTGGTGGTCTACCCTTGGACCCAGAGGTTCTTTGAGTCCTTTGGGGATCTGTCCACTCCTGATG
>   CTGTTATGGGCAACCCTAAGGTGAAGGCTCATGGCAAGAAAGTGCTCGGTGCCTTTAGTGATGGCCTGGC
>   TCACCTGGACAACCTCAAGGGCACCTTTGCCACACTGAGTGAGCTGCACTGTGACAAGCTGCACGTGGAT
>   CCTGAGAACTTCAGGCTCCTGGGCAACGTGCTGGTCTGTGTGCTGGCCCATCACTTTGGCAAAGAATTCA
>   CCCCACCAGTGCAGGCTGCCTATCAGAAAGTGGTGGCTGGTGTGGCTAATGCCCTGGCCCACAAGTATCA
>   CTAAGCTCGCTTTCTTGCTGTCCAATTTCTATTAAAGGTTCCTTTGTTCCCTAAGTCCAACTACTAAACT
>   GGGGGATATTATGAAGGGCCTTGAGCATCTGGATTCTGCCTAATAAAAAACATTTATTTTCATTGC

```
dna_ = input("Enter the DNA sequence to translate: ")
def translate():
  translate()
for i in range(0,len(dna_),3):
    dna = dna_[i:i+3]
    if dna == "ATA" or dna == "ATC" or dna == "ATT":
      print ("I")
    elif dna == "CTA" or dna == "CTC" or dna == "CTG" or dna == "CTT" or dna == "TAA" or dna =="TTG":
      print ("L")
    elif dna == "GTA" or dna == "GTC" or dna == "GTG" or dna == "GTT":
      print ("V")
    elif dna == "TTC" or dna == "TTT":
      print ("F")
    elif dna == "ATG":
      print ("M")
    else:
      print ("X")

def txtTranslate():
  translate()
  with open("normalDNA.txt", "r") as f:
    normalDNAoutput = f.readlines(translate)
    print (f.read())
  return (normalDNAoutput)
```

I would like it to output the interpreted code but it gives nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your external text file:

```
ACATTTGCTTCTGACACAACTGTGTTCACTAGCAACCTCAAACAGACACCATGGTGCATCTGACTCCTGA
GGAGAAGTCTGCCGTTACTGCCCTGTGGGGCAAGGTGAACGTGGATGAAGTTGGTGGTGAGGCCCTGGGC
AGGCTGCTGGTGGTCTACCCTTGGACCCAGAGGTTCTTTGAGTCCTTTGGGGATCTGTCCACTCCTGATG
CTGTTATGGGCAACCCTAAGGTGAAGGCTCATGGCAAGAAAGTGCTCGGTGCCTTTAGTGATGGCCTGGC
```

Here is the code, looks prettier and clean:

```py
def translate(dna_):
    codes = []
    for i in range(0,len(dna_),3):
        dna = dna_[i:i+3]
        if dna == "ATA" or dna == "ATC" or dna == "ATT":
            codes.append("I")
        elif dna == "CTA" or dna == "CTC" or dna == "CTG" or dna == "CTT" or dna == "TAA" or dna =="TTG":
            codes.append('L')

        elif dna == "GTA" or dna == "GTC" or dna == "GTG" or dna == "GTT":
            codes.append('V')
        elif dna == "TTC" or dna == "TTT":
            codes.append('F')
        elif dna == "ATG":
            codes.append('M')
        else:
            codes.append('X')

    print('-'.join(codes))

with open("normalDNA.txt", "r") as f:
    dna_seqs = f.readlines(translate)

for dna_ in dna_seqs:
    translate(dna_)
```

It should output like this:

```
X-F-X-X-X-X-X-V-F-X-X-X-L-X-X-X-X-X-X-I-X-L-L-X
X-X-V-X-X-X-X-X-V-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X
X-L-L-V-V-X-X-X-X-X-X-F-F-X-X-F-X-X-L-X-X-X-X-X
L-X-X-X-X-L-X-X-X-L-M-X-X-X-X-X-V-X-X-V-M-X-X-X
```

Answer (score 1):

The preferred way to translate DNA is by using a translation table, i.e. a dictionary of codon:aminoacid pairs.

Here is one example:

```
def translate(seq, table):
    result=''
    for i in range(0,len(seq),3):
        codon = seq[i:i+3].upper()
        if codon in table:
            result += table[codon]
        else:
            result += 'X'
    return result

s = 'ACATTTGCTTCTGACACAACTGTGTTCACTAGCAACCTCAAACAGACACCATGGTGCATCTGACTCCTGAGGAGAAGTCTGCCGTTACTGCCCTGTGGGGCAAGGTGAACGTGGATGAAGTTGGTGGTGAGGCCCTGGGCAGGCTGCTGGTGGTCTACCCTTGGACCCAGAGGTTCTTTGAGTCCTTTGGGGATCTGTCCACTCCTGATGCTGTTATGGGCAACCCTAAGGTGAAGGCTCATGGCAAGAAAGTGCTCGGTGCCTTTAGTGATGGCCTGGC'
table = {"ATA":"I", "ATC":"I", "ATT":"I", "CTA":"I",
         "CTC":"L", "CTG":"L", "CTT":"L", "TAA":"L", "TTG":"L",
         "GTA":"V", "GTC":"V", "GTG":"V", "GTT":"V",
         "TTC":"F", "TTT":"F",
         "ATG":"M"}

translate(s,table)
```

Output:

```
'XFXXXXXVFXXXLXXXXXXIXLLXXXLXXLXXXXXXXXMXLVVXXXXXXXXXXLXXXXXLXXLXIXXLLMLXXXXIXXXLMXXXXXVXXVMXXX'
```